# Why unable to recall verbbox from vebatimbox package in enumeration list?

Tags: enumerate, verbatimbox

I am using the nice package [verbatimbox](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/verbatimbox/verbatimbox.pdf)  which allows verbatim as second argument to href.  This works

```
\begin{verbbox}https://some_url_1/report.htm\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
```

But when I put the above inside enumeration list, it stops working. i.e. nothing is printed.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{verbbox}https://some_url_1/report.htm\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox

\begin{verbbox}https://some_url_2/report.htm\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex gives

[image]

But now

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{verbbox}https://some_url_1/report.htm\end{verbbox}
      \theverbbox
\item \begin{verbbox}https://some_url_12report.htm\end{verbbox}
      \theverbbox
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex now gives blank PDF page. Nothing on it at all.

Why is that? And how to make it print same as before but in enumeration list?

TL 2023, and updated to latest now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX is in a particular state after `\item` and `verbbox` doesn't take care of this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\theverbboxitem}{%
  \kern-\labelwidth\kern-\labelsep
  \theverbbox
  \kern\labelwidth\kern\labelsep
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{verbbox}https://some_url_1/report.htm\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbbox}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \leavevmode\begin{verbbox}https://some_url_1/report.htm\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbboxitem}
\item Something else
\end{enumerate}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\fbox` just to make sure that the dimensions are right. What happens, among other problems, that the list indentation is inserted in front of the verbatim material.