# How to use verbnobox from verbatimbox package with href?

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, verbatimbox

using package [verbatimbox](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/verbatimbox/verbatimbox.pdf) one can use target (second argument) of href as verbatimbox. But I am trying to use the version with no box.

I found some issue when using the boxed version. Here is an example showing the problem first, and then showing my attempts at using the no boxed version

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
    
%code thanks to 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697506/why-unable-to-recall-verbbox-from-vebatimbox-package-in-enumeration-list
\newcommand{\theverbboxitem}{%
  \kern-\labelwidth\kern-\labelsep
  \theverbbox
  \kern\labelwidth\kern\labelsep
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \leavevmode\begin{verbbox}7_Inverse_hyperbolic_functions/7.1_Inverse_hyperbolic_sine/186_7.1.2-d_x-^m-a+b_arcsinh-c_x-^n\end{verbbox}
      \href{https://some_url_1/report.htm}{\theverbboxitem}
\item \leavevmode\begin{verbbox}7_Inverse_hyperbolic_functions/7.2_Inverse_hyperbolic_sine/186_7.1.2-d_x-^m-a+sin_x_y+b_arcsinh-c_x-^n\end{verbbox}
      \href{https://some_url_2/report.htm}{\theverbboxitem}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using lualatex gives

[image]

It wraps there at the end. Which I do not want. I thought it is due to using the box.

Here is also a screen shot from large document I build showing the problem

[image]

I was trying to see if I can have version without the boxes, it will not do that.

It turned out the package provide a `noboxed` version! But I am not able to figure how to use the no boxed version. When I try

```
\begin{verbnobox}my nice site\end{verbnobox}
\href{https://site_URL_here/index.htm}{\theverbbox}
```

I get

[image]

The above is not an href. clicking on it does nothing. the dot below is empty box.  I understand what is going on. But can't figure how to make no boxed version work same as boxed version in href.

Doc says

[image]

Ok, so I can't recall them using `\theverbbox`. But then how to use them with href? I tried using it directly

```
\href{https://site_URL_here/index.htm}{\begin{verbnobox}my nice site\end{verbnobox}}
```

But got compile error.

```
Missing } inserted. ...begin{verbnobox}my nice site\end{verbnobox}}
```

My question is: How to use `verbnobox` instead of `verbbox` as second argument of `href` if one can't recall it and can't insert it directly?  I basically just want a way to use Verbatim as second argument of href. The above package does this, but I do not want the box around it in order to fix the wrapping shown in the above example.

here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{verbnobox}my nice site\end{verbnobox}
\href{https://site_URL_here/index.htm}{\theverbbox} %not correct

%this is also not correct
%\href{https://site_URL_here/index.htm}{\begin{verbnobox}my nice site\end{verbnobox}}

\end{document}
```

TL 2023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that verbatimbox is a good solution. You get a box and that means no sensible line break. I would use `\urldef` to store an url like text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\textwidth=4cm
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document} 
\begin{myverbbox}{\myTarget}https://some_url_with_^many_%*?_strange_characters/report.htm\end{myverbbox}

\href{https://some_url_with_^many_%*?_strange_characters/report.htm}{\myTarget}

\bigskip

\urldef\mytarget\nolinkurl{https://some_url_with_^many_%*?_#strange_characters/report.htm}
\href{https://some_url_with_^many_%*?_strange_characters/report.htm}{\mytarget}

\end{document}
```

[image]